# ngclick triggered twice when clicking button Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/h08qQF2qlVE3arERpdfi?p=preview) to create a  notification each time a button is clicked.

The example works well on the emulator but on the phone it is triggered twice!
Here is the controller

```
angular.module('starter.toolsController', ['ui-notification'])

.controller('toolsController', function($scope, Notification) {

$scope.BottomCenter1 = function() {
    Notification.warning({message: 'Messenger d entreprise', positionY: 'bottom', positionX: 'center'});
};
```

and the button:

```
<button class="box1" ng-click="BottomCenter2()"> MyRhoom </button>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is this all of the relevant code? Also your button calls `BottomCenter2()` but you gave us the code for `BottomCenter1()`.

Comment: I have 6 buttons and they are all the same. so it is box1, box2, ...etc and BottomCenter1(), BottomCenter2(), etc..

Comment: Do you think you can make a Bunker, or JSFiddle with just your example working?

Comment: Try using FastClick, or lookup ngTouch. Angular 1 was never really designed for mobile.